# Why is my Perl script to print lines prepended with line numbers not working?

Tags: perl, file-io

I intend to open a text file and read lines. And add the letter "pp" with line number in front of it.

The text file is as follows.

```
39828513 39829926 1413 hsa-mir-6719
41252946 41254434 1488 hsa-mir-6889
62331112 62332604 1492 hsa-mir-4758
```

And I want to have the output as follows:

```
pp1 39828513 39829926 1413 hsa-mir-6719
pp2 41252946 41254434 1488 hsa-mir-6889
pp3 62331112 62332604 1492 hsa-mir-4758
```

I have written a code but I don't feel its working fine.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open (fh, " < file.txt") || die ;
while ($line=<fh>)
{
 chomp ($line);
    for (my $i=1; $i <= ($#line); $i++)
    {
    print "pp$i\t$line";
    }
}
```

Comment: sure you need perl for this?

Comment: see http://www.catonmat.net/blog/perl-one-liners-explained-part-two/

Comment: actually perl is not needed, but i am trying to hone up my perl programming skills. i am new to perl and still learning

Comment: `cat -n file.txt`. (Also: Look up `$.` in `perlvar`)

Comment: @Sobrique `cat -n file.txt | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*\([0-9]\+\)\t/pp\1 /'` to match request! ;-)

Comment: Can you not `sed 's/^\s*/pp/g'`

Comment: @Sobrique `g` switch is useless, with `/^` at begin! And no, because there is a *tab*, not a *space* after number, by using `cat -n`.

Comment: @Sobrique and other geeks, for fun only, you could even use: `sed -n 'x;/^$/ s/^.*$/1/;G;h;s/^\(.*\)\n/pp\1 /p;g;s/\n.*$//;/^9*$/ s/^/0/;s/.9*$/x&/;h;s/^.*x//;y/0123456789/1234567890/;x;s/x.*$//;G;s/\n//;h' <file.txt`

Comment: Or under [tag:bash]: `{ sed 'N;s/^\(.*\)\n/pp\1 /'< <(sed =);} <file.txt`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take advantage of the `$.` variable:

```
print "pp$. $_" while <>;
```

Comment: use like: `cat myfile | perl -pe 'print "pp$. "'`

Comment: @xtofl avoid useless `cat`!  Use: `perl -pe 'print "pp$. "' <myfile` instead.

Comment: perl -pe 'print "pp$. " ' < myfile_name   this works, completely fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

First, when you read using `while ($line = <fh>)`, you *are* reading the file one line at a time, so there is no need for your `for` loop.

Second, when you use [`strict`](https://metacpan.org/pod/strict), you must declare your variables. It is good practice to to declare them in the smallest possible scope. When you use a bareword filehandle such as `fh`, you are creating a variable global to the package. This can create action at a distance.

Therefore, you can use [`open my $fh, '<', '...'`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#open-FILEHANDLE-EXPR) and `while (my $line = ...)`.

You do not need to [`chomp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#chomp-VARIABLE) each line as you are going to need to add a newline when printing anyway.

Perl's built-in variable [$.](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#pod26) provides the current line number for the last filehandle accessed.

Finally, if `open` fails, you should print the [`$!`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#pod26) variable so you can figure out why it failed.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# If provided, use first command line argument
# for file name.
my $filename = @ARGV ? $ARGV[0] : 'file.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $filename
    or die "Failed to open '$filename': $!";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    print "pp$.\t", $line;
}
```

Now, if `$.` did not exist, you would initialize a counter before the `while`-loop, and increment it once for each line printed in the loop body, as in

```
my $counter = 1;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    print "pp$counter\t", $line;
    $counter += 1;
}
```

Comment: You should mention the built-in `$.`

Comment: I used the built-in $. and the code works absolutely fine. It was advisable not to use a for loop, when once "while" reads all the lines.

Answer (score 1):

A Perl one liner on the command line is all you need:

Linux/OSX:

```
$ perl -ne 'print "pp$. $_"' infile > outfile
```

Windows:

```
> perl -ne "print qq(pp$. $_)" infile > outfile
```

Just replace `infile` and `outfile` with the file names you want read from and write to. If the `outfile` doesn't already exist, it will create it automatically. If it already exists, it will overwrite it.